# How do I search for a particular object within an array of JSON objects using postman

Tags: java, android, json, postman-testcase

How do I query for a particular BusStopCode from within a JSON object in a JSON array

```
 "value": [
        {
            "BusStopCode": "01012",
            "RoadName": "Victoria St",
            "Description": "Hotel Grand Pacific",
            "Latitude": 1.29684825487647,
            "Longitude": 103.85253591654006
        },
        {
            "BusStopCode": "01013",
            "RoadName": "Victoria St",
            "Description": "St. Joseph's Ch",
            "Latitude": 1.29770970610083,
            "Longitude": 103.8532247463225
        },
```

for example if I want to find only the first object then the bus stop code I would query is 01012

my current URL query request looks like this-
http://transport/dataservice/BusStops?BusStopCode=01012

here **http://transport/dataservice/BusStops** is my URL

and **?BusStopCode=01012** is my path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***tl;dr:*** **You can't unless they implemenet it on the server side.**

Postman is only the client side.

When you are sending a URL - the server reads it and have an implementation for this specific url / url + parameters in our case.

If the server have an implementation for something like `http://transport/dataservice/BusStops?BusStopCode=01012` They should expose it to you. You can't guess what is their API.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your response data using [JSONpath Visualizer](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-team-collections/documentation/1794236-eab3402a-73ab-4b3d-99c9-62a4bf180e5a) in Postman.

To enable the Visualizer, please paste the following code in the Test section of Postman where you are creating your request.

```javascript
let template = `
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.0.2/jsonpath.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input id="filter" style="width:450px;" type="text" placeholder="Example query: $..name.first">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button id="resetButton" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Reset</button>
        <input id="showErrors" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
        <span class="item-text" style="font-family:courier;">Show Evaluation Errors</span>
      </div>
      <div id="errors" style="font-family:courier;color:red;display:none;"></div>
      <div>
        <p id="content" style="font-family:courier;color:green;font-size:18px;"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
pm.getData( (error, value) => { 
    const extractedData = jsonpath.query(value, '$');
    
    $(function() {
        $('#filter').keyup(function() {
            try {
                let filteredData = jsonpath.query(extractedData, $(this).val());
                $("#content, #errors").empty();
                $("#content").append("<pre><code>" + JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 4) + "</code></pre>");
            } catch (err) {
                console.info(err);
                $("#errors").empty();
                $("#errors").append("<pre><code>" + err + "</code></pre>");
            }
        });
    });
    
    $( "#resetButton" ).click(function() {
        $("#content, #errors").empty();
        $("#filter").val('');
        $("#content").append("<pre><code>" + JSON.stringify(extractedData, null, 4) + "</code></pre>");
    })
})

$(function() {
  $("#showErrors").on("click",function() {
    $("#errors").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
</script>`

pm.visualizer.set(template, pm.response.json())
```

Here is the example.

[image]

Sample data is also provided for better understanding.

[image]